# How to get tasks by user in Asana

Tags: php, api, asana

I've just started using the Asana API to make myself a little tool to get an overview of all tasks assigned to me.

I can do all kinds of things, like getting all Workgroups, Projects, Users, Tasks by Project etc. But somehow I cannot find how to get all Tasks per user.

When you login to Asana, you get an overview of all tasks assigned to you. That's what I try to achieve using the API. Below you'll find the GitHub project I'm using right now.

#### Reference

Github: [Asana API](https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  If you have a specific problem with your code, please clarify your question and post the code you are having a problem with, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @frasnian I thought I made it quite clear that I am having trouble getting some specific information from the Asana API. As a code example is irrelevant at this point, I left it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. From [the documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query), under *Querying for Tasks*, it suggests using the `assignee` parameter for filtering for this purpose. The adjacent example entitled **Show tasks assigned to me in a workspace or organization** seems particularly useful. You would make a request to:

`/tasks?workspace=14916&assignee=me`

If you want all tasks across all workspaces, you'll have to iterate over your workspaces and make this kind of query.

Comment: Isnt possible to get all task assigned for user across the account?

Comment: No, that particular query is not possible.

Comment: :( many interesting system can be done if that API is available

Comment: As mentioned, you can currently access all the tasks assigned to a user by iterating over the workspaces. It just takes multiple API calls.